# two equivalents equations with different representations in the plane

Tags: calculus, parametric

Consider the parametric curve $$C:\begin{cases}
        x  = 4e^{t/4} \\
        y  = 3e^{t} \\
    \end{cases}
    $$
A cartesian equation for this curve is $y=\frac{3x^4}{256}$. The problem is that $x=4e^{t/4}$ is positive so in the plane the representation of the curve will be in the first quadrant, while the equation $y=\frac{3x^4}{256}$ is valid for all $x\in \mathbb R$. so the two curves coincide only on the first quadrant but the graph of $y=\frac{3x^4}{256}$ has another part which in the second quadrant which is symmetric to the first part by the $y-axis$. Is is possible that the two equations have different graphs in the plane ? how can we explain that ? thank you for your help !

Comment: When you raise $x$ to the $4^{\text{th}}$ power (or any other even power for that matter) you introduce spurious branch of your curve, since $x^{2n} = (-x)^{2n}$.

Comment: Yes I see that, but can we say that the cartesian equation represents the graph only for $x>0$ or can we say that the parametric equations above is a parametrization of **only** the first part in the first quadrant of the equation.. that is  $ \begin{cases} 
        x  = 4e^{t/4} \\
        y  = 3e^{t} \\
    \end{cases}
    $ if and only if $y=\frac{3x^4}{256}$ **and** $x>0$ so without the part $x>0$ the parametrization is false, Am I right ?

Comment: If you just want a Cartesian equation with exactly the same graph as the parameteric, use $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{256y}{3}}=x$$. If you want a functional equation $y=f(x)$, use a piecewise defined function that is undefined for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to explain. You are given a map $${\bf f}:\quad {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}^2, \qquad t\mapsto\bigl(4e^{t/4}, 3e^t\bigr)\ ,$$
and you have proven that all points of the set $C:={\bf f}({\mathbb R})$ satisfy the equation $3x^4-256y=0$.

Note that even the map
$${\bf g}:\quad {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}^2, \qquad t\mapsto\bigl(4, 3\bigr)\ ,$$
would have the property that all points of ${\bf g}({\mathbb R})$ would satisfy this equation.

It is another thing if you start with the equation $3x^4-256y=0$ and are asking for a map ${\bf h}$ that produces  the solution set  of this equation in a bijective way. The given ${\bf f}$ will certainly not qualify.